# How to correctly override .ng-hide class in order to change hiding/showing nature?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

When using **`ng-hide`** or **`ng-show`** directives a `.ng-class` is added or removed so DOM elements are visible or not.

However they kinda get positional "removed" as for example, hiding or showing two continous `div` elements one on top of the other.

```
<div ng-show="condition1">First div</div>
<div ng-show="condition2">Second div</div>
```

So, if `condition1` evaluates to false first div will be hidden *BUT* second div will take the position which the just hidden div took.

**How can I avoid that? I *only* want DOM elements to be invisible but not to get somehow *removed*.**

## First workaround.

I tried to overried `.ng-hide` class and getting a secondary class, `only-hide`, for elements on which I wanted this effect:

```
.ng-hide.only-hide {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

But didn't get results so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve and maintain the space occuped by the div you can't use **directly** `ng-hide` or `ng-show`.

You can use the **ng-style** directive as following:

```
<div ng-style="conditionHide1">First div</div>
<div ng-style="conditionHide2">Second div</div>
```

then your `conditionHide1` and `conditionHide2` should be like

```
if (condition1)
    $scope.conditionHide1= {'visibility': 'hidden'}; // then div1 will hidden.
else
    $scope.conditionHide1= {'visibility': 'visible'}; // then div1 will visible.
if (condition2)
    $scope.conditionHide2= {'visibility': 'hidden'}; // then div2 will hidden.
else
    $scope.conditionHide2= {'visibility': 'visible'}; // then div2 will visible.
```

You can change the visibility of the button by changing the `$scope.conditionHide1` and `$scope.conditionHide2` according to your conditions.

**Solution2** by using a custom directive:

Create a new directive named **condition** and relative to an **A**ttribute. Set-up a `watch` to watch the **value** of the attribute and, based on the value, set to the **element** (in this case the `div`) an appropriate css style. The value is mapped to the variable `showDiv` which change his value by clicking on the button. Clicking on the button, the value `showDiv` became the opposite `!showDiv` and the watch change the visibility from `visible` to `hidden` and vice-versa.

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.directive('condition', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
     scope.$watch(attributes.condition, function(value){
       element.css('visibility', value ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
        });
    }
  };
})

.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.showDiv = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <div condition='showDiv'>Div visible/invisible</div>
  <button ng-click='showDiv = !showDiv'>Hide div or show it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I really like the solution2 approach as it doesn't have to deal with other CSS properties which may break something. What do you think about my solution?

Comment: Your solution is 'wortking fine' but I'm used to not override components and to not use the css !important tag. So, if your job/work is to do something quickly, it's fine, but if you want to study and exploit the whole angularjs potentiality I recommend you to use another solution. Consider my humle opinion as an advice to think outside the box :)

Comment: Yeah I agree mostly with your position. First solution, find it cumbersome but second one I think is great. Could your extend a little bit on how a directive is made up?

Comment: I just added the directive explaination.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved it with this second class approach by setting:

```
.ng-hide.only-hide {

  visibility: hidden !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

As Angular sets `.ng-hide` with `display:none`, I make it invisible but *present* setting `display:block`.